# How to replace TensorFlow 2.0 "contrib" function calls?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am migrating my code from TensorFlow 1.13.1 to TensorFlow 2.0. However, "contrib" modules will be removed and I can't find a replacement for these functions:

```
tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer

tf.contrib.image.transform
```

I thought about forking the whole "layers" and "image" directory, but this could get really messy, so I'd rather avoid that.

Thanks!

Comment: can try `tf.keras.regularizers.l2`

Comment: See [Sunsetting `tf.contrib`](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md). Under [List of projects](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md#list-of-projects) there is a table with the "fate" for each of the projects. There is also [this Google document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FLFJLzg7WNP6JHODX5q8BDgptKafq_slHpnHVbJIteQ/edit?usp=sharing) with a more detailed and updated "map" of symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [regularization functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers)' page of TF 2.0. There you can find l1, l2, and l1 & l2 regularizations.

Image preprocessing is now based on Keras syntax, you can find some hints [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).